# How to put a method returning a list of widgets inside another list of widgets? (inline style)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method that returns a list of widgets.

```
List<Widget> _buildDrawerItems() {
  return [...];
}
```

How to include the method inline like this?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      ...,
      _buildDrawerItems(),
      ...
    ],
  );
}
```

So far I've been using `.addAll()`. But I feel that's untidy.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: []
    ..addAll([...])
    ..addAll(_buildDrawerItems())
    ..addAll([...])
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is literally just a small edit of your code. You can use the **spread operator** (`...`) like this, and it builds the list of widgets.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ..._buildDrawerItems(),
      ],
    );
  }
```